# Trigger double click - mouse event - google map - console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, console

Is it possible to trigger dblclick Mouse Event on  Google Map from google chrome console? I want zoom in from console.

Answer (score 0):

You can used the `map.setZoom(/* zooming values in integer*/)` in the console.

For the below code:

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var map;
        function initMap() {
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 12.972442, lng: 77.580643},
          zoom: 8
        });
       }
     </script>
     <script async defer
       src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
   </script>
 </body>
```

on the console if you execute `map.setZoom(16)` this zooms to the center.

Answer (score -1):

I found such solution

```
var mev = {
  stop: null,
  latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0,-90.0)
}

google.maps.event.trigger( map, 'doubleclick', mev );
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me or maybe I am doing something wrong

For example how to zoom in via console (with triggering double click) in:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events